# Compare two time strings from array

Tags: php, datetime, string-comparison

i have a array which is look like that

```
[0] => 2014/12/18 02:44:26 GMT+05:30
[1] => 2014/12/18 02:44:27 GMT+05:30
[2] => 2014/12/18 02:44:37 GMT+05:30
[3] => 2014/12/18 02:44:47 GMT+05:30
[4] => 2014/12/18 02:44:57 GMT+05:30
. 
.
.

[6043] => 2014/12/18 23:17:47 GMT+05:30
[6044] => 2014/12/18 23:17:57 GMT+05:30
[6045] => 2014/12/18 23:18:02 GMT+05:30
[6046] => 2014/12/19 02:11:21 GMT+05:30
[6047] => 2014/12/19 02:11:22 GMT+05:30
```

I want to compare two time strings and get the last index where time goes 23 to 1 means, should not be more than a day(24 HR)

Comment: Is your array sorted?

Comment: yes Array is Sorted but array has more than 6000 points

Comment: If your element type is `Datetime`, I suggest using **binary search** to quickly filter elements that refer to the end of a day. If you element type is string, I think you have to traverse through whole array.

Comment: its String type of array

Answer (score 0):

```
$time1 = "08:00:00";

if (strtotime($time1) < strtotime("23:59:00")) {
   ...
}
```